# Installing Gradle plugin v3.0

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I really do not understand why it was always so much trouble of adding Gradle plugin in the Android app.

I started my project by creating a fresh app.
This is in my gradle.properties:

```
distributionUrl = https \: //services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.0-all.zip
```

and this project and says build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
     repositories {
         jcenter ()
     }
     dependencies {
         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0'

     }
}
```

and the error I get is
 [image]

Comment: "trouble of adding Grage plugin in the Android app" this does not make any sense, Why would anyone try to add Gradle plugin to an Android app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The build tools for Android do not support version 3.0 at present.

If you check the gradle build tool project on [Bintray](https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.android.tools.build.gradle/view), you can see the latest available versions.

At present, that is `2.2.0-rc1` so to use it you should add this to your project-level build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-rc1'
```

If you want to use the latest stable version `2.1.3` replace it with,

```
compile 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
```

You should also checkout [tools.android.com](http://tools.android.com/) for the latest up-to-date information on the Android Build Tools